# AutoLayout issue with ULabel

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel

I have 2 labels attached at top with "zero" constraint. One label have font 12, other 15. I face the problem, that i have unnecessary space between text and cell border. Please take a look:

[image]

You can see that left space to top is less then second. How to fix that?

Comment: you mean the gap between that blue line and text A16? you should have asked your question more clearly.

Comment: you are talking about the baseline alignment between the two labels ?? I din get your question properly

Comment: @Santo no, between top and text A16

Comment: @SandeepBhandari i talk about difference (gap) between top of "A16" text and top of "У" text.

Comment: @evgeniy-kleban : Thats what I meant buddy :) if both of their base lines are aligned your problem is solved isnt it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evgeniy Kleban,

As per your question you have two labels and for both the labels you have attached the constraint as 0 :)

My suggestion assign top constraint as 0 to only one :) Lets assume you are okay with the placement of label y :) Then delete the top layout constraint on label A16 and instaed hold control and drag from label y to label A16 and when you leave a popup appears select center vertically :)

This will ensure both the labels base lines will be aligned properly :) Hence your problem is solved :)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check if the second label has option "relative to margins" checked, just uncheck it.

If you just want the labels to be on the same `y` position, just delete the second label's top constraint and add a baseline constraint between two labels.